# Ensure filename is in datetime correct format

Tags: regex, datetime, python-2.7

I want all my files to be off format: `2013-03-31_142436.jpg`
i.e. `%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S`

I have a script to rename that way but would like to check if the filename is of the format first.  I do:

```
for filename in files:
    # check filename not already in file format
    filename_without_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[0];
```

How do I check `filename_without_ext` is of format `%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S`

Answer (score 2):

Use `re`:

```
import re
if re.match(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{6}$', filename_without_ext):
    pass # of the right format
```

This will just check it *looks* like it has a chance of being a valid date. Use Martijn's answer if you require it to *be* a valid date.

Comment: `\d` matches digits, `{4}`, `{2}` and `{6}` are quantifiers; match that many digits exactly.

Comment: It just reads "Check at the start of the string there's four digits followed by a hyphen followed by two digits followed by a hyphen, followed by two digits, followed by an underscore, followed by 6 digits to end the string

Answer (score 2):

Just try to parse it as a timestamp:

```
from time import strptime

try:
    strptime(filename_without_ext, '%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S')
except ValueError:
    # Not a valid timestamp
```

The `strptime()` test has the advantage that it guarantees that you have a valid datetime value, not just a pattern of digits that still could represent an invalid datetime (`'1234-56-78_987654'` is not a valid timestamp, for example).